# Run Azure Webjob on self hosted integration runtime

Tags: python, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-data-factory

I have a simple question: Is it possible to choose in which Azure Integration runtime a triggered webjob runs ? I would like to run a webjob on a self hosted integration runtime.
The webjob runs a python scripts that needs to access Shared Folder behind a company firewall. The self hosted integration runtime is the company domain, that would resolve the issue.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean of self hosted integration runtime? do you mean that run the python webjob not in azure, but locally?

Comment: Hi Dave, I want to check if you have solved the issue or not? If not, could you please explain more about the question?